# Tracing the "sender hierarchy" in Scala actors

Tags: scala, actor, tooling

I'm maintaining a couple of actor-based Scala applications at the moment, and one question I find myself asking all the time is *Who sends that message?*

For example, I find the piece of code that prints the scary message I found in the logs:

```
case ReportFailedUpdates(stuff) =>
  log("The horror! The horror! " + stuff)
  dieHorribly()
```

and I want to find out what might be the cause.  If I weren't using actors, I could hit `Ctrl+Alt+H` (at least in Eclipse) and find out who 'called' this 'method' (and who called that, and who called *that*).  With actors, I find myself searching for `! ReportFailedUpdates(` to find which actors send this message, then searching for the senders of the message *that* actor was reacting to, *etc* (and usually drawing the result on paper).  This has two disadvantages:

- It's slower, since Eclipse is doing a text search over the (potentially many) project(s) and I'm having to note stuff down
- It doesn't necessarily find all occurrences, since maybe this was sent with `!?`, or maybe someone put two spaces between the `!` and the `ReportFailedUpdates`, or, or, or....

What I'd *love* is some tooling support that lets me find out where a message could have come from - roughly the equivalent of a call hierarchy for non-actor-based code.

Are there any tools that do it? Is this a feature of the ScalaIDE for Eclipse that I just haven't discovered? If I use IntelliJ will my life be better?

**Update**

My example may have been misleading.  This isn't just about figuring out what's gone wrong when it all falls over -  I also find myself doing this a lot when I pick up a new system and need to figure out how it works. Seems like there isn't yet a tool to do it. Guess I'll have to have a think myself about how you could start to statically extract (and maybe visualize) the message flow graph...

Comment: Yes, [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) will make your life better. I don't think it solves this problem, but it has life-changing awesomeness :-)

Comment: @dave: I couldn't agree more! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is quite the hefty desire, and I'd be extremely impressed if someone were to write it, but I haven't seen anything like that as yet.

Tracing it will be very difficult since there's no "stack" to trace.  I'm curious why you don't do this, though:

```
case ReportFailedUpdates(stuff) =>
    log("The horror! The horror! %s (sent by %s)".format(stuff, sender))
    dieHorribly()
```

That would at least give you the current link in the chain.

As well - I'm a Vim guy so excuse my ignorance - does your IDE not have a better search mechanism, such as Regexes?

Comment: That helps to find that sender, but what about the next link up the chain? Unless I log the sender every time a message is received, but then I've just replaced my problem with a log parsing problem.

I suspect it's not possible to statically determine this with absolute certainty, but I'd settle for finding invocations of the sending methods (!, !?, et al.) where the arguments are of the same type (or a subtype of) the type under my cursor. Eclipse does have regexes, but then the search is slower again (plus "now you have two problems").

Comment: Oh I understand.  The issue is that there is no "chain" in message-based asynchronous programming.  There's no "stack".  I've written a lot of Actor code and this has never been a problem so you might have a systemic issue, but aside from that, the only "easy" way I can see to get what you want is to store the chain in the message as it travels.  You can store the sender and the received message and then at the point of horrible death, you can dump the this stack you've accumulated.

Comment: It's certainly possible that these systems aren't structured in the most idiomatic actor style, but I'm stuck with that unless I want to risk some major refactoring.  Accumulating the 'stack' is quite a nice idea - helps less with the static "how does this system work?" questions, but useful for debugging. Accepting your answer because it seems what I want doesn't exist! Thanks for your help :)